# SQL 2008 - Call for named formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, call, divide

So lets say I have this code:

```
Select
 'Position Date' =              todaypositiondate
,'Realized' =           round(sum(realizedccy*spotsek),0)

FROM T1 
    group by todaypositiondate
    order by todaypositiondate desc
```

If I wan to divide 'Realized' with 100.
How can I set `'new' = 'Realized'/100` instead of  `'new' = (round(sum(realizedccy*spotsek),0))/100` ?

Best regards

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's possible but takes more steps, and more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do that but here is one way using a `CTE`. You can also use subqueries, but both of these steps are pretty pointless for the math you want to do, and will decrease performance. You can't reference a column alias by it's alias within the same statement like you are trying to do. This includes referencing it in the `where` or `group by` or `order by` clauses

```
;with cte as(
Select
    todaypositiondate as 
    round(sum(realizedccy*spotsek),0) as Realized
from T1 
    group by todaypositiondate
    order by todaypositiondate desc)

select 
    todaypositiondate,
    Realized,
    Realized / 100 as RealizedDivHundred
from cte
```